# Excel 2010 & SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba, stored-procedures

I need a macro that, for each cell in a column, executes an SQL Server stored procedure which gets a parameter for a different cell in a different column (but in the same row).

i.e. Fill column B with a result of a stored procedure which get the parameter from Column A..

Examples:

- B2 is the result of stored procedure which use the A2 value as input
- B3 is the result of stored procedure which use the A3 value as input
- B4 is the result of stored procedure which use the A4 value as input
- B5 is the result of stored procedure which use the A5 value as input

Is there a way to do this without VBA?

Comment: i.e. a stored procedure from a database in a Microsoft SQL server...

Comment: do you really need a stored procedure if you are working with Excel Sheet 2 columns? What's the logic of this *stored procedure*? How do you want to process the data in column A to return to column B?

Comment: I need the stored procedure or a select statment... I am trying to select a value of a field in a database table where another field equal the cell in the column A....i.e. Select FieldB where FieldA = ??

Comment: It seems to me that you'd be better off selecting all the data from SQL Server into a separate worksheet once, then using a lookup function to get the data.

Comment: And how to use the lookup function?

Comment: Can I pass multiple values to the Lookup function as parameters??

Comment: @JeffRosenberg are you sure "selecting all the data from SQL Server"? SQL Server tables can be very large indeed. user2100151 I would suggest that you use a query to return only those rows that are relevant to your spreadsheet. This may require VBA, but it is possible to use a linked server http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306397. Why do you wish to avoid VBA.

Comment: @Remou I meant selecting all the data needed for this particular speadsheet. My answer below mentions both using a prewritten view or creating a query. My point was to bring the data into Excel with a one-time query, rather than one cell at a time.

Comment: There are advantages in a user defined function that gets data a cell at a time via a query as long as the connection is fast and you can depend on indexes. It leaves the user a lot of room.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I end it up getting the table into the sheet and then using the LOOKUP function to send multiple cells value to get a specific value in the table

[Check here for how to use the LOOKUP Function](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-excel/archive/2012/04/26/using-multiple-criteria-in-excel-lookup-formulas.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able do this without VBA by defining a connection to the SQL Server database and importing the data into your spreadsheet that way. You can use the [Data Connection Wizard](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-edit-and-manage-connections-to-external-data-HA010342379.aspx) to create a connection to a table or view in your database, or to enter your own SQL statement to query the database, and add that data to a new worksheet.

Then, in the original worksheet, you can use a lookup function like `VLOOKUP` to find a match.

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, Table_Named_Range, Column_of_Result, 0)
```

Let me know if you need a more detailed explanation.